# Using shared libraries with GLFW/GLEW

Tags: c++, glfw, glew

Installing GLFW and GLEW onto different Linux machines has always been a hassle. After finally getting everything setup, I'm attempting to compile an assignment for my Computer Graphics class but receive the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: a2.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'a2' failed
make: *** [a2] Error 1
```

I've been attempting to recompile with `-fPIC` in multiple different ways using `g++` but the documentation is difficult to understand in regards to where I'm supposed to place the option.

I've read different help requests on this issue with -fPIC and shared libraries, but none of them have relevant or sufficient answers.

Here's the makefile I'm using:

```
COMPILE_FLAGS=-c -fPIC

all: a2

a2: a2.o
    g++ -fPIC a2.o -o a2 -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor -lGLEW

a2.o: a2.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c a2.cpp
```

Comment: You aren't compiling a2.cpp using -fPIC...

Comment: Something like this? @immibis 

     `g++ -std=c++11 -c -fPIC a2.cpp`  I'm still getting the same errors. :[

Comment: Did you recompile a2.o after that? If you just run `make` it won't know the command changed so it won't know it needs to run the new command.

Comment: Actually your compile step produces a.out and not a2.o if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Deleting `a2.o` fixed the issue! After recompling with `-fPIC`, everything is good to go. I deleted the `.exec` and `.o` afterwards, and then recompiled without `-fPIC` to see what would happen and it worked fine so I'm not sure what is taking place.